# return number of solutions to the equation x1 + x2 + x3 = num

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method that accepts as a positive integer num parameter and returns the number of solutions to the equation

x1 + x2 + x3 = num

When the three xs are positive integers between 1 and 10.
The method should also print out these solutions, each solution in a separate line. The print order does not matter.

I tried:

```
public static int solutions (int x1, int x2, int x3, int counter, int num)
{
    if(x1 > 10 || x2 > 10 || x3 > 10) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num) {
        System.out.println(x1 + "+" + x2 + "+" + x3);
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        return solutions (x1 + 1, x2, x3, counter, num) +
               solutions (x1, x2 + 1, x3, counter, num) +
               solutions (x1, x2, x3 + 1, counter, num);
    }
    return counter;
}

public static int solutions (int num)
{
    if (num < 3 || num > 30) {
        return 0;
    }
    return solutions (1, 1, 1, 0, num);

}
```

The problem is that I repeat the results, The problem is that I get repeated results, for example num = 5, I get:

```
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
2 + 1 + 2
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 1 + 3
```

Instead of

```
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 3 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
3 + 1 + 1
```

How can I avoid repeating it twice?

Comment: Only print solutions where `x1 <= x2 <= x3`.

Comment: Note that you don't have to search over all values of `x3`: calculate it from `num - x1 - x2`, and reject if that value is outside the 1..10 range.

Comment: Lets say you have `foo(int a, int b){if (a<3 && b<3){ foo(a+1, b); foo(a, b+1); }`. When you call `foo(1,1)` it will internally call `foo(2,1)` and then `foo(1,2)`. Now `foo(2,1)` will generate calls to `foo(3,1); foo(2,2)` and `foo(1,2)` calls to `foo(2,2); foo(1,3)`. As you see `foo(2,2)` is invoked ***twice***. You need to decide which of those calls is not needed. Under what conditions should and shouldn't `foo(2,2)` be called.

Comment: This is a question from an assignment in the open university, Introduction to computer science using java course

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd approach it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Number of solutions: "+ solutions(5));
}

public static int solutions(int num) 
{
    if (num < 3 || num > 30)
        return 0;
    else
        return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1);
}

private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3)
{   
    int valid = 0;          
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num)
    {
        valid = 1;
        System.out.println(x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3 + " = " + num);            
    }                
    if ((x3 < 10) && (x1 + x2 + x3 < num))
    {
        return valid + solutions(num, x1, x2, ++x3);
    }
    else if ((x2 < 10) && (x1 + x2 < num)) 
    {
        return valid + solutions(num, x1, ++x2, 1);    
    }
    else if ((x1 < 10) && (x1 < num))
    {
        return valid + solutions(num, ++x1, 1, 1);
    }  
    else
    {
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit late, but I may suggest an optimization: replace `else if ((x2 < 10) && (x1 + x2 < num)) ` with `else if ((x2 < 10) && (x1 + x2 + 1 < num))` and `else if ((x1 < 10) && (x1 < num))`  with `else if ((x1 < 10) && (x1  + 2< num))` to prevent redundant recursion calls. for example if num=5 4 not needed calls were made for 1+4+1, 4+1+1, 3+2+1 and 2+3+1.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely expected behaviour for the code you've provided; the first time your function is called it is going to do this (I've removed the last two arguments for the sake of brevity):

`return solutions(2, 1, 1) + solutions(1, 2, 1) + solutions(1, 1, 2)`

Given that for all three arguments you are adding 1 until you get to 10, you would expect (for example) `2 + 2 + 1` to be produced by both the first and the second call at some point.

One solution to your problem would be to pass a collection object of some kind through the recursion which you add solutions to each time you find one. Then when you find a new one you check if is contained in your collection as well as checking if it adds up to the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with... (it works with any amount of variables in the equation)

```
public static int solutions(int num)
{
    return solutions(num, 3, 1, ""); // 'varsInTheEq' represents the numbers of varibelas in the equation (in this case: 'x1 + x2 + x3 = num' which is 3)
}

private static int solutions(int num, int varsInTheEq, int value, String builder)
{
    if (num == 0 && varsInTheEq == 0) // if we solved the equation
    {
        System.out.println(builder);
        return 1;
    }

    if (varsInTheEq == 0 || value > num)
        return 0;

    int r1 = solutions(num - value, varsInTheEq - 1, 1, builder + value + " ");
    int r2 = solutions(num, varsInTheEq, value + 1, builder);

    return r1 + r2;
}
```